# Show that there is a Lipschitz-continous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ for that $f(A)=[0,b]$ ($0<b\leq 1$ and $A\subseteq[0,1]$)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, transformation, lipschitz-functions, measurable-functions

I am working on the following task:

Let $A\subseteq[0,1]$ Lebesgue measureable with $\lambda^1(A)>0$. Show that there is a Lipschitz-continous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ and $0<b\leq1$ with $f(A)=[0,b]$.

There is the following hint for the task: Choose a closed set $F\subseteq[0,1]$ with $f\subseteq A$ and $\lambda^1(F)>0$ and set $f(x):=\lambda^1(F\cap[0,x])$ for $x\in[0,1]$. Now show that $f(F)=f(A)=f([0,1])$ holds.

I am not really sure how to prove the statement here. Can somebody help me with this task? This is what I have so far, but I am really not sure if this is good:

Since $\lambda^1(A)>0$ there is an open-set with $U\supseteq A$ with $\lambda^1(U)>0$. Look at $F=U^C$, the closed set, which is the complement of $[0,1]$, obviously $F\subseteq A$ and $\lambda^1(F)>0$.
Now define $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ as $f(x)=\lambda^1(F\cap[0,x])$ for $x\in[0,1]$. Now we see that $f(F)=\lambda^1(F\cap F)=\lambda^1(F)>0$ and $f([0,1])=\lambda^1(F\cap[0,1])=\lambda^1(F)>0$, also $f(A)=\lambda^1(F\cap A)\geq\lambda^1(F)>0$ (since $F\subseteq A$). I think from here we can rescale and move the function to reach $f(A)=[0,b]$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): please show your attempt(s) to apply the hint and explain where and why you are stuck.

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't really understand what to do with the hint, that's why I am aksing

Comment: @AnneBauval I have added what I have so far to the post

Comment: You have to choose $F$ more carefully to make sure its measure is not $0$. Use inner regularity https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure

Comment: Next, $f$ is not defined on *subsets* of $ [0,1]$ but on *elements* of it. For instance $f(1)=\lambda^1(F)$.

Comment: @AnneBauval could you please explain how exactly I should choose $F$? Regarding the other comment, I see what you mean. Do you have a suggestion on how I could define $f$?

Comment: For the choice of $F$ simply use thé inner regularity of $\lambda^1$ (as defined in the link). As for $f$, already defined in your hint, don't change it.

Comment: @AnneBauval and how do I continue from here?

Comment: @AnneBauval How can I now show that $f(F)=f(A)=f([0,1])$?

Comment: monotonicity + intermediate value theorem

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific, I don't know how you mean to apply it here.

Comment: Last hint: use that $f$ is non-decreasing and continuous and $f(0)=0$. And $f$ is defined a priori on *elements* of $[0,1]$, so think about the (perhaps non-immediate) meaning of $f(X)$ for a *subset* $X\subseteq[0,1]$. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_directe